# An (intuitive) explanation for the emergence of $\pm$ in the expansion of $\cos\Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)$ in terms of $\cos x$?

Tags: trigonometry, intuition

For some angle $\alpha$, we have :
$$\cos(2\alpha) = 2\cos^2\alpha - 1$$
$$\cos\Big(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\Big) = \pm\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos\alpha + 1}{2}}$$
I want to gain a deeper and more intuitive understanding of why '$\pm$' emerges here.

At first, I thought that the emergence of $\pm$ implies that the answer is not unique, which is the case in most of the uses of $\pm$. For example, $\sqrt{4} = \pm 2$. This implies that the answer can be both $2$ and $-2$.

But, the cosine of any angle is always unique. So, in this particular case, I think that the use of $\pm$ implies that it is either $\Bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos\alpha + 1}{2}}\Bigg)$ or $\Bigg(-\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos\alpha + 1}{2}}\Bigg)$. From my point of view, this also implies that ***only the value of $\cos\alpha$ (even if the values of other trigonometric functions at $\alpha$ are provided) is not sufficient to evaluate the value of $\cos\Big(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\Big)$ as there are infinitely many values of $\alpha$ for some given $\cos\alpha$ and for those possible values, overall, two values of $\cos\Big(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\Big)$ emerge.***

The reason that $\pm$ doesn't emerge in the expansion of $\cos(2\alpha)$ in my opinion, is that for some given value of $\cos\alpha$, the value for $\cos(2\alpha)$ is unique for all possible values of $\alpha$ (that are co-terminally related to each other).

I have mathematically proved that for all possible values of $\alpha$ for some given $\cos\alpha$, there is one and only one value that $\cos(2\alpha)$ corresponds to but rather two values that $\cos\Big(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\Big)$ corresponds to.

So, I want to verify if the way I interpret the emergence of $\pm$ and especially, the statement that I have formatted with bold and italics are correct.

Thanks!

**PS :** I can add the proof that I reference in this post if that helps to make the question clearer. Let me know if I should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's worth pointing out that most of the time you can regard uses of the "$\pm$" sign like this as slightly informal: if you know $x^2 = k$ for some $k > 0$, then concluding that $x = \pm \sqrt{k}$ is really just a shorthand for saying "thus $x = \sqrt{k}$ or $x = - \sqrt{k}$, but I don't know which".

Written long-form like this, I think it becomes a lot clearer what you can and cannot conclude.

Also, using the example above, it might be the case in a given situation that only the case of $x = -\sqrt{k}$ (say) is possible due to additional information which places constraints on $x$. For example, you might know that $x$ is actually some function $f(y)$ of another variable $y$, and $f(y)$ only ever produces negative values. But in a vacuum, by only manipulating the equation $x^2 = y$ you won't be able to conclude this.

I think put this way, we can clearly evaluate the truth of what you've written in bold: it does not follow that knowledge of $\cos \alpha$ is not enough to evaluate $\cos \frac{\alpha}{2}$ directly from your manipulation---it might be possible, it's just that your equation doesn't tell you that it is. But as stated in other answers there are explicit examples that show that your statement in bold is true.

Thus, in retrospect with such examples in mind, there can't be any possible way to manipulate your first equation in order to obtain a unique possibility for $\cos \frac{\alpha}{2}$ (since this isn't actually true!).

***Note on square roots in general*:** It is a common misconception that "$\sqrt{4} = \pm 2$" (using the usual notation common in mathematics). Formally the square root function $\sqrt{x}$ has only a single value, the so-called *principal square root*, which is just the positive one. That is, for example $\sqrt{4}$ is literally equal to $2$. The "$\pm$" creeps in when we are solving equations, since if we know that $x^2 = k$ (with $k > 0$) then $x = \sqrt{k}$ or $x = - \sqrt{k}$, but we don't know which. Often we write $x = \pm \sqrt{k}$ as a shorthand for this, but that is all that is going on.

Comment: So, does this render the statement in bold as correct since we need additional information to evaluate $\cos(\alpha/2)$ (more specifically, the quadrant that it lies in), which can not be provided simply by the knowledge of the value of trigonometric functions at $\alpha$?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu I've edited my answer. To summarize: the conclusion of your bold statement is correct, but you can only know for sure once you find a pair $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ for which $\cos \alpha_1 = \cos \alpha_2$ but $\cos \frac{\alpha_1}{2} \not = \cos \frac{\alpha_2}{2}$. Without finding an actual counterexample, you only can't yet conclude that there is a unique answer, but you haven't actually discounted the possibility.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu I've also just added a note on square roots in general.

Comment: Have a look on my comment on @RobertIsrael 's answer. I have observed that if $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are two co-terminal angles with a difference of an odd multiple of $2\pi$ between them satisfy such a condition. Do you think a separate post regarding a proof-verification of my statement would be worth it? I, as a $10^{th}$ grader, find the proof to be pretty interesting, though. The proof would also include why the value of $\cos(2\alpha)$, in contrast is unique.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Well, if you've got a question about your proof of that fact, then feel free to post another question! But it sounds to me (just from what you've said) that you've got a pretty good understanding of what's going on there (you're probably using the fact that when $k$ is an odd integer, then $\frac{2 \pi k}{2}$ is equal to $2 \pi m + \pi$ for some integer $m$---then since $\cos$ is periodic with period $2 \pi$, this means that $\cos (\alpha + 2 \pi k)$ is unchanged, but $\cos (\frac{\alpha + 2 \pi k}{2}) = \cos (\frac{\alpha}{2} + \pi)$ and so changes sign).

Comment: Exactly! You understand me perfectly, thank you! :-)

Comment: I have one last question. I have proved the statement in bold for $\sin$ as well but I might have to think harder for $\tan$. Do you agree that if two real numbers, $a$ and $b$ are provided to us such that $-1\leq a\leq 1$ and $-1\leq a\leq 1$ and $a^2+b^2=1$, then, there exist infinitely many values of $\alpha$ that satisfy $\cos\alpha=a$ and $\sin\alpha=b$ and if we arbitrarily take any two of those possible values of $\alpha$, say $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then $\tan\dfrac{\lambda}{2}=\tan\dfrac{\mu}{2}$ for all values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ (basically since the period of $\tan$ is $\pi$)?

Comment: Indeed: note that $\tan \alpha = \frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}$, and also that $\cos (\alpha + \pi) = - \cos(\alpha)$ and $\sin (\alpha + \pi) = - \sin(\alpha)$. This means that if $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ differ by (say) $\pi$, then both $\sin$ and $\cos$ change their signs when you replace $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. But since $\tan$ is the ratio of $\sin$ and $\cos$, these sign changes cancel out!

Comment: Shouldn't that imply that there should be no $\pm$ in the expansion of $\tan(x/2)$ in terms of $\tan x$ as for some given value of $\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\alpha$, the value of $\tan(\alpha/2)$ is unique for all possible values of $\alpha$ unlike the case with $\sin(\alpha/2)$ and $\cos(\alpha/2)$? I might need to think deeper about it but I just want to ask once before I dive in, thanks!

Comment: It could actually still be the case that a $\pm$ appears, but because of the underlying relationship between $\sin$ and $\cos$, only one of the signs is possible (i.e. you can use additional information). By looking at the $\tan$ double angle formula, I think you're going to wind up with a quadratic equation in $\tan x$ to solve. Try to discard on of the two solutions. :)

Comment: I was still confused about the emergence of $\pm$ in *tangent* here. So, I thought it'd be best to ask a separate question regarding it. Please check it out here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772455/an-intuitive-explanation-for-the-emergence-of-the-pm-symbol-in-the-expansion

Answer (score 1):

Because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and since $$\cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1+\cos\alpha}{2},$$ we obtain a right identity:
$$\left|\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\alpha}{2}}.$$
Now,for $\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\leq0$ we obtain:
$$\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=-\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\alpha}{2}}$$ and for $\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\geq0$ we obtain:
$$\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\alpha}{2}}$$

In my opinion the statement $$\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\alpha}{2}}$$ without some adding words is wrong.

Also, in real numbers $\sqrt4=2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But, can you please verify if my interpretation is correct too? That is what I intended the question to be focused on. Thanks!

Comment: @Rajdeep Sindhu Your reasoning is wrong because in any case $\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}$ gets an unique value for given $\alpha$. See please better my post. I just explained this point.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But, that is not my claim. I claim that $\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$ does not get a unique value for given values of $\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\alpha$ (for which, there exist infinitely many values of $\alpha$, all of which are co-terminally related to each other. Is that correct?

Comment: @Rajdeep Sindhu Your last statement is true, but it has no any relation with the identity $\left|\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\alpha}{2}}.$

Answer (score 1):

Knowing $\cos(2\alpha)$ does not determine what the sign of $\cos(\alpha)$ is.  For example, $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha = \pi$ both have $\cos(2\alpha) = 1$, but one has $\cos(\alpha)=1$ and the other has $\cos(\alpha)=-1$.

Comment: Thanks, first of all! But, is the statement that I have written in bold right?

Comment: Even if we have $\cos\alpha = 1/2$ and $\sin\alpha = \sqrt{3}/2$ given to us, the value of $\cos(\alpha/2)$ is still not unique, in my opinion. For example, two possible values of $\alpha$ can be : $(\pi/3)$ and $(-5\pi/3)$. For these two values, the values of $\sin(\alpha/2)$ are : $1/2$ and $-1/2$. This is just an example to justify my claim.